# After connection is closed, and opened again, it no longer exists

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, jt400

I created a servlet in domino server, the first time I call it I see no errors but after I see this :

> java.sql.SQLException: The connection does not exist.
>   at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:389)
>   at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.checkOpen(AS400JDBCConnection.java:394)
>   at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:1868)
>   at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:1703)

I must now restart every time the domino server if I want to call the servlet
I tried not to close the connection in the code and it worked but this solution can cause performance problems

Any other solution would be appreciated

EDIT :

After using Apache DBCP, I have another errors :

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(P??oolingDataSource.java:175)
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStat??ement(PoolingDataSource.java:301)

COODE to get/pool the connection :

> public class ConnexionAS400 {

```
public static ConnexionAS400 connexionAS4000= null;
private static Connection connAS400 = null;

public static ConnexionAS400 getInstance(){
    if(connexionAS4000 == null)
        connexionAS4000 = new ConnexionAS400();
    return connexionAS4000;
}

private ConnexionAS400(){
    String Url = "jdbc:as400://172.31.5.100";
    String Username = "DEVATIRD";
    String Password = "ATIRD";
    String Driver = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver";
    try
    {   
        Class.forName(Driver);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(Url,Username,Password);
        PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, new GenericObjectPool(null), null, "SELECT 1", false, true);
        ObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(poolableConnectionFactory,GenericObjectPool.DEFAULT_MAX_ACTIVE,GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW,GenericObjectPool.DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT,GenericObjectPool.DEFAULT_MAX_IDLE,false,true);
        PoolingDataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
        connAS400 = dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError exno)
    {
        System.out.println("ERREUR: Impossible de charger la classe");
        exno.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERREUR: Impossible de charger le driver JDBC AS400.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public  Connection openConnectionAS400() {
    return connAS400;
}

public  void closeConnectionAS400() {
    try {
        connAS400.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out
        .println("ERREUR: Lors de la fermeture de la connection.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a threading issue.  You should be using a connection pool to manage the JDBC connections such as [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/), or your container provided mechanism, if there is one.

Comment: Now I have another errors with Apache DBCP  

java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.  
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:175)  
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:301)

Comment: @sadiqmrd Please update your question with the code you are using to get/pool the connection.